# How to unmask on submit RobinHerbots / Inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, mask, jquery-inputmask

I use this [plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) and want to unmask input on submit.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bothering, I solved this with .inputmask({"mask": "8(999) 999-9999",  'removeMaskOnSubmit' : true});